# I'm trying to append colours to an empty list in a for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dictionary, matplotlib

```
colors = []
for lab, row in netflix_movies_col_subset :
    if row["lab"] =="Children" :
       colors.append("Children")
    elif ... :
        ...
    elif ... :
        ...
    else:
```

[ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6fbu6.png)

I don't know how to append colors to the "Children" data, in order to be able to identify it after visualizing with matplotlib.

PS: It's a guided project, as I'm just

Comment: Use `iterrows`: `for lab, row in netflix_movies_col_subset.iterrows():`

Comment: Or `for lab in netflix_movies_col_subset["lab"]:`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to map each category of a column to a color, create a `dict` and use `map` like:

```
# df = pd.DataFrame({'category': ['Children', 'Parent']})

d = {'Children': 'red', 'Parent': 'blue'}
df['color'] = df['category'].map(d)
print(df)

# Output:
   category color
0  Children   red
1    Parent  blue
```

Comment: @Dinomain_. Does it work for you?

Comment: I found my way around it. Turned out to be a minor indentation problem with my original code .

Answer (score 0):

#Iterate over rows of netflix_movies_col_subset in an empty list

```
colors = []
for genre, row in netflix_movies_col_subset.iterrows() :
     if row['genre'] =="Children":
        colors.append('red')
     elif row['genre'] == "Documentaries" :
        colors.append('blue')
     elif row['genre'] == "Stand-Up" :
        colors.append('green')  
     else:
        colors.append('black')
```